# 8GB microSD image being showed as 16GB

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, sd-card

I have a backup of my Raspbian on a .img file. The problem is that even though the file is less than 8GB when I try to flash it on a 16GB microSD card, I get an error that there is not enough space.

This is what I get when I run `sudo fdisk -l` on my .img file:

```
Disk Rasp4.img: 14,9 GiB, 15987638272 bytes, 31225856 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xa8c7ffa4

Device          Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
Rasp4.img1       8192    93814    85623 41,8M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
Rasp4.img2      94208 15564799 15470592  7,4G 83 Linux
```

When I open the .img file in `Disks`, I see that there is 8GB of free space. Why is this free space being included in the .img file (and yet is not being shown by `fdisk -l` as a partition that can be trimmed) and how can I remove it?

Comment: You should specify **HOW** you "have a backup of my Raspbian on a .img file"

Comment: All apologies ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> this free space ... is not being shown by fdisk -l

Yes it is.  Look at the first line of your `fdisk` output.  That "free space" isn't part of any partition.  This is the same as if you had formatted a 16 GB card with one 8 GB partition.

> The problem is that even though the file is less than 8GB

Are you sure about that?  I suspect it is actually 14.9 GiB, and what you mean is the root filesystem in it is only ~8GB.

If so, try this (you will need 8GB free to do it):

```
dd if=Rasp4.img of=smaller.img bs=4096 count=1945600
```

Then run `fdisk` on `smaller.img` to check.  The math here is 4096 (block size in bytes) * 1945600 (number of blocks) = 7969177600 / 512 (sector size used by fdisk) = 15564800 (one sector beyond the "End" of the 2nd partition).

Comment: I can take a screen shot where `Disks` literally has a graphic that states I have 8GB of free space on the .img file if you would like... It is, however, a partition that fdisk does not display--and so, I am not sure how to trim it.

Comment: Yes, I believe you.  My point is **fdisk DOES show the free space**.  It just does not show it as a partition, because it isn't.   "Disks" may indicate the space in a manner orthogonal to the way it shows information about a partition, but it isn't showing you a partition either.  To illustrate: If you fire up `fdisk` on a device or image and delete all the partitions, it will then not show any table -- just the summary up top.  Which does say clearly, "14.9 GiB".

Comment: ...I think what you are confused about is the fact that *not all the space on a device (or in an image file) is necessarily formatted into partitions.* An unformatted 500 GB hard drive has 500 GB of free space and zero partitions (although since they usually come formatted, this is not what you will see with a new drive).  Make sense?

Comment: I suggest to use `sudo parted Rasp4.img unit s print free`. This will also show the free space and clarify the situation.

Comment: @goldilocks, that was precisely the misunderstanding. Thank you. Is there anyway I may trim this free space nonetheless?

Comment: Yes.  Copy the image out using `dd` as described above.  Since this creates a copy, you can try it out without risk of doing any damage.  If you run `fdisk -l` on the copy, the total size given in the first line should be smaller.

Comment: It worked! Many thanks! But I am curious, does the file system get priority when using dd? How did it know not to copy the empty free space unlike before? Would the same work if the empty space was inside a partition?

Comment: It didn't know.  `dd` doesn't care what it is copying.  It just copies raw blocks, byte for byte.  The reason the excessive free space was left out was because of what I described as "the math" at the end.  It only copied the first ~8GB of the image.